# Can I use foreach to return only a certain type from a collection?

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

If I enter the code below, I get an error. Basically, the foreach will break when it comes across a Control that isn't a label.

```
foreach (Label currControl in this.Controls()) {

...
}
```

I have to do something like this.

```
foreach (Control currControl in this.Controls()) {
    if(typeof(Label).Equals(currControl.GetType())){

    ...
    }

}
```

can anyone think of a better way of doing it without me needing to check the type? Can I somehow get foreach to skip the objects that aren't Labels?

Comment: Are you on .NET 3.5? Can you use LINQ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can do something like this

```
foreach(var label in this.Controls().OfType<Label>()) {
}
```

`OfType<T>` will ignore types that cannot be cast to T. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx

Comment: cool I just figured it out!

any idea how you would do it without 3.5?

Answer (score 7):

Brian has given the most appropriate answer in terms of `OfType`. However, I wanted to point out that there's a better way of checking for types in cases where you *do* need to do it. Instead of your current code:

```
if(typeof(Label).Equals(currControl.GetType())){

...
}
```

You can use:

```
if (currControl is Label)
{
    Label label = (Label) currControl;
    // ...
}
```

or:

```
Label label = currControl as Label;
if (label != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that both of these alternatives will *also* include subclasses of `Label`, which your original code doesn't.